# Reclassifying sub-property objects as properties in GEE

Tags: zonal-statistics, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am replicating [the Hansen Global Forest Change tutorial from GEE](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorial_forest_03a) to calculate annual forest loss by country in Africa. My code so far is:

```js
//Country shapefiles
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');
var Africa = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('wld_rgn', 'Africa'));


//Hansen Global Forest Change image with multiple bands
var gfc2014 = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015').clip(Africa);
print("Hansen data", gfc2014);


var lossImage = gfc2014.select(['loss']); 
var lossAreaImage = lossImage.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()); 
Map.addLayer(lossAreaImage);

var lossYear = gfc2014.select(['lossyear']);

var lossByYear = lossAreaImage.addBands(lossYear) 
  .reduceRegions({ 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum()
  .group({
      groupField: 1}),
  collection: Africa, 
  scale: 30
});


print("loss by country and year", lossByYear);
```

When I print the feature collection, I find that the forest loss data is stored not as a property, but as a sort of sub-property, under the label "groups". How do you reclassify these variables such that they export?

Original code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7941159e374327c8d984f3ec2a6baf8c), but these are all GEE datasets, so the above will run fine.

Edit update: I also tried to extract the objects by year:

```
var loss0 = lossByYear.map(function(f) {
  var loss2000 = ee.Feature(ee.List(f.get('groups')).get(0))
      .get('sum');
  return f.set('loss2000', loss2000);
});
```

And get the error: FeatureCollection (Error)
Error in map(ID=00000000000000000000):
Element.get, argument 'object': Invalid type. Expected: Element. Actual: Dictionary.

I also tried converting the objects as follows:

```
var loss = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(lossByYear.get('groups'))
  .map(function(el) {
    var d = ee.Dictionary(el);
    return ee.Feature(null, { yearString: ee.Number(d.get('group')).format("20%02d"), 
                              lossArea: d.get('sum'),
                              yearNumber: ee.Number(d.get('group')).add(2000)
    });
  }));
```

But get the error: FeatureCollection (Error)
List.map: Parameter 'list' is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var addGroups = function(feature) {
  var statsFormatted = ee.List(feature.get('groups'))
  .map(function(el) {
    var d = ee.Dictionary(el);
    return [ee.Number(d.get('group')).format("20%02d"), d.get('sum')];
  });
  var statsDictionary = ee.Dictionary(statsFormatted.flatten());

  return feature.set(statsDictionary);
};

print(lossByYear.map(addGroups))
lossByYear = lossByYear.map(addGroups)
```

Comment: Thank you! This mapping function worked perfectly!